# Using VPN Google APP Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a VPN with my company through Google Compute Engine. 
Is it possible to use that VPN with Google APP Engine?
How can I connect the app with the VPN?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can indeed use the VPN to connect to Google App Engine Flexible Environment. [App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) is based on Google Compute Engine, which makes this possible.

[As described in this article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml), you can specify network setting in your `app.yaml` configuration file which will allow you to connect to your *GAE Flexible application*.